# flyway - a way to do distributed?

Tags: database, migration, flyway

I've been very impressed with the amount of time flyway saves me doing basic things:  creating a schema from scratch, and updating it to a particular version.

I've been a bit frustrated whenever anything out of the ordinary happens:  I have a customer-specific view that needs to be applied to some schemas; I have a branch version that has some scripts the base version does not; I'd like to run the same flyway installation on multiple schemas.

In all of these cases, I find myself manually moving .sql files around to try to do different things; this is very error-prone, and flyway has no forgiveness at all about anything changing in the history of a schema.  (This makes me a bit antsy about using flyway for production schemas, but that's another topic).

It seems like database-versioning has finally caught up to code versioning at about, say, 2000:  you can have one single line of changes, and that works great.  But in the same way that DVCS expanded what you could do with experimentation and branching, there is a need in database versioning to move in this way.

Is this something flyway is thinking about, working on, or has ways to do that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you maintain just one view but implement feature toggling instead for each customer? That way you maintain one schema and all custom views but break out the logic into "features." Then in a property file or database table you look up the feature's toggle (true/false) to determine how to join or build the SQL.

Comment: Doesn't fix my problem, but thanks, interesting idea.